Why is α-truxillic acid not meso compound?
I know that for a compound to be meso it should be optically inactive and should have multiple chiral centres but in case of α-truxillic acid, it is optically inactive due to centre of symmetry being present and it also has 4 pseudo chiral centres then why is it not meso compound? Do we not count pseudo chiral centres as chiral centres for checking if a compound is meso or not?

